# amp-img error: Layout not supported for: container

Tags: amp-html

Trying to validate my amp-img. In this example: http://staging.laineygossip.com/Sasha-Celeb-Finds-Sienna-Miller/Lifestyle/24695/amp#development=1

I get the error: `Layout not supported for: container`
In the console, the error is: `The specified layout 'CONTAINER' is not supported by tag 'amp-img'`

Not sure what this error means.

So far I can't find anything in the docs that relates to this error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`container` is not supported by the `layout` attribute in `<amp-img>`. The [AMP Docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/amp-img.html) provide a list of supported layouts you can use.

Answer (score 10):

As per google AMP docs, layouts supported:

**FILL, FIXED, FIXED-HEIGHT, FLEX-ITEM, NODISPLAY, RESPONSIVE**

Also look at this example, I don't think you need quotes around the layout type: https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/news_article/

So it should look something like this:

```
  <figure>
    <amp-img src="/img/landscape_village_1280x720.jpg"
      width=1280
      height=768
      layout=responsive></amp-img>
   <figcaption>Here is a responsive image.</figcaption>
 </figure>
```

Comment: This is exactly the issue. The error displayed is completely wrong. Setting up height and width resolved it.

Answer (score 10):

Amp defaults to layout="container" if there is no width and height attribute set.  **So you can get this error even though you have not set a layout.**

At the time of my response, this is also the case for amp-img which do not support layout="container" - hence your error.

[Layout Documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout.html)

Fix your issue by adding width and height or specifying an appropriate layout.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if we do not mention the width and height of an amp image. If the width and height attributes are not specified for an amp image (amp images must be given an explicit size as in width/ height in advance so that the aspect ratio can be known without fetching the image), the inferred layout is container which is not a supported layout for the same [AMP Docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-img) and so the error occurs.